# JPQL Entity1 join Entity2 where Entity1 is mapped in Entity2 but not the other way round

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

If I have two Entities Entity1 and Entity2 which are mapped on both sides (or at least Entity2 is mapped in Entity1) I can do

```
select e1 from Entity1 e1
left join e1.entity2 e2
where e2.id is null
```

Is there an equivalent for this if I do not have `e1.entity2` but only `Entity2.entity1`?

Comment: You mean "SELECT e1 FROM Entity2 e2 JOIN e2.entity1 e1 WHERE ..."

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally change your tables round the other way. There is an option of using `RIGHT JOIN` but I would fail any code if I saw a `RIGHT JOIN` during a code review;

```
SELECT *
FROM Entity2 e2
LEFT JOIN Entity1 e1
    ON e2.IdField = e1.IdField
WHERE e1.IdField IS NULL
```

Also, you appear to be missing your join criteria, it's best to declare these

Comment: Regarding your code snippet: I need the results of Entity1, not Entity2, and if I query for those using your snipped I would always get zero results, wouldn't I?

Comment: @JacobS this is the opposite of the original code snippet you posted? Try adding the row with the ON statement to your original query, see if you get what you're after.